# Entity Framework ViewModel with Multiple Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building MVC CRUD pages for the Events table, where I have one to many between table (C) DeviceChannel and table (D) Events. Table (C) is described by a 2 foreign keys to tables (A) Device and (B) Channel. There is a further foreign key to describe the EventType.

The DeviceChannel does not have a description (so I can't use this as the look up for Events directly) though it does have various values associated with it so I have to include the Device and Channel tables.

I have built a ViewModel with the above tables but when I try to create a Controller, I get errors complaining there is no Metadata for the ViewModel. No keys defined between the tables. All the tables have keys and load up correctly in EF database-first.

I am using VS2013 with .Net 4.5.2
I did try using a repository after following the NerdDinners example, without success.
**Questions:**
Should I be using a ViewModel to develop this solution.
If I use a ViewModel, how do I resolve the metadata/key issue when trying to scafold the controller?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by simplifying the ViewModel.

```
public class DeviceChannelEventsViewModel
{
    public SelectList eventType { get; private set; } 
    public SelectList deviceChannel { get; private set; }
    public CRHSEvent crhsEvent { get; set; }
    public DeviceChannelEventsViewModel(SelectList _deviceChannel, SelectList _eventType, CRHSEvent _crhsEvent)
    {
        deviceChannel = _deviceChannel;
        eventType = _eventType;
        crhsEvent = _crhsEvent;
    }
    public DeviceChannelEventsViewModel(SelectList _deviceChannel, SelectList _eventType)
    {
        deviceChannel = _deviceChannel;
        eventType = _eventType;
        crhsEvent = new CRHSEvent();
    }
}
```

When I created the selectlist for deviceChannel, I joined the Device and Channel tables to the devicechannel table:

```
DeviceChannelRepository dcr = new DeviceChannelRepository();
IEnumerable<DeviceChannel> dc = dcr.FindAllDeviceChannelsDescribed(); 
SelectList deviceChannels = new SelectList(dc.Select(s => new 
{ 
    DeviceChannelID = s.DeviceChannelID ,
    DCDescription=string.Format("{0} | {1}",s.Device.DeviceName,s.Channel.Description)
}).ToList(), "DeviceChannelID", "DCDescription");

SelectList eventType = new SelectList(db.EventType, "EventTypeID", "Description");
DeviceChannelEventsViewModel dCEViewModel = 
new DeviceChannelEventsViewModel(deviceChannels, eventType);
```